SALESFORCE_AUTHENTICATOR Enabled for a user
How to identify if a given user is already linked with SALESFORCE_AUTHENTICATOR. I want to delink user from SALESFORCE_AUTHENTICATOR using an apex logic but before doing it I want to put a validation check in my code, if the user is not using the SALESFORCE_AUTHENTICATOR then my code should not go for delink.
Taking about - App Registration: Salesforce Authenticator on user detail page.

I think you would be looking to use SOQL to query the TwoFactorMethodsInfo object to see what verification method users are using. This Object has a boolean flag on it for HasSalesforceAuthenticator which should give you the check you need.
Note it states that your user running the Query will need the Manage Multi-Factor Authentication in API permission to access this object.
So a query would look something like
SELECT HasSalesforceAuthenticator, UserId FROM TwoFactorMethodsInfo WHERE UserId = '1234'

